# How to set up a RedisService using Redis from `ioredis`?

Tags: typescript, redis, jestjs, nestjs, ioredis

NestJs v9.0.0, ioredis v5.3.2, jest v29.5.0.
I'm unable to properly set up my redis service to get it working in both, jest unit tests or starting the nest app. I have a service `RedisService` which imports Redis from 'ioredis'.

Getting either issues when running the unit tests(jest) for the `RedisService`, or if I fix them then I get the below error when starting Nest:

## Error #1

When starting Nest or running the e2e:

```
    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RedisService (?). Please make sure that the argument Redis at index [0] is available in the RedisModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is RedisModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If Redis is a provider, is it part of the current RedisModule?
    - If Redis is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RedisModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Redis */ ]
      })
```

Above error is reproduced when starting the app or running the e2e tests.

This is my `RedisService` with which the unit tests work fine, but when starting the app or running the e2e tests I get the Error #1:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common';
import Redis from 'ioredis';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService implements OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor(private client: Redis) {} // <-- This is possibly the "issue". Unit tests work fine with this DI but app and e2e fail

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.client = new Redis({
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: +process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    });
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.client.quit();
  }

  async set(key: string, value: string, expirationSeconds: number) {
    await this.client.set(key, value, 'EX', expirationSeconds);
  }

  async get(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
    return await this.client.get(key);
  }
}
```

I have tried different approaches, and this was the one the unit tests finally worked fine, but clearly not when running e2e tests or starting the app.

However I can easily fix it by making my RedisService not to inject Redis from 'ioredis' into the constructor and instead instantiating it in onModuleInit lifecycle hook. BUT if I stop injecting it into the constructor, then its unit tests fail because the redisClient is an empty object instead of the mock I want it to be. Which leads to fix Error #1 but instead get Error #2 described below.

## Error #2

In case of the tests failing, I get the following kind of errors:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')`
and `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

The unit tests instead fail BUT the e2e and app work successfully if I change the `redis.service.ts` to:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import Redis from 'ioredis';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private client: Redis; // no injection in the constructor

  async onModuleInit() {
    this.client = new Redis({
      host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
      port: +process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then the tests fail because the redisService is an empty object.

### Context

These are the specs, `redis.service.spec.ts`:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import * as redisMock from 'redis-mock';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

describe('RedisService', () => {
  let service: RedisService;
  let redisClientMock: redisMock.RedisClient;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    redisClientMock = {
      set: jest.fn(),
      get: jest.fn(),
    };
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        RedisService,
        {
          provide: Redis,
          useValue: redisMock.createClient(),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    redisClientMock = module.get(Redis);
    service = module.get<RedisService>(RedisService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('set', () => {
    it('should set a value in Redis with expiration date', async () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(redisClientMock, 'set');
      await service.set('my-key', 'my-value', 60);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('my-key', 'my-value', 'EX', 60);
    });
  });

  describe('get', () => {
    it('should return null if the key does not exist', async () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(redisClientMock, 'get').mockReturnValue(undefined);
      const value = await service.get('nonexistent-key');
      expect(value).toBeUndefined();
    });
    it('should return the value if the key exists', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(redisClientMock, 'get').mockReturnValue('my-value');
      const value = await service.get('my-key');
      expect(value).toBe('my-value');
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my
`redis.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

@Module({
  providers: [RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

RedisModule is in the imports array of the module where it is a dependency.

I guess using ioredis we just have to avoid injecting it in the constructor, but then how can I fix `redis.service.spec.ts` so that it gets the redisClient on time? Should it be injected as a dependency in the constructor? In any case, how should Redis be implemented in Nest so that both, e2e and unit tests work smoothly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it after trying different things. Running the unit tests with this command `NEST_DEBUG=true npm test` helped me narrow down the issues in the end until the unit tests run successfully. Things that fixed it:

1. Create file `redis.provider.ts` like this:

```
    import { Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
    import Redis from 'ioredis';
    
    export type RedisClient = Redis;
    
    export const redisProvider: Provider = {
      useFactory: (): RedisClient => {
        return new Redis({
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 6379,
        });
      },
      provide: 'REDIS_CLIENT',
    };
```

2. Provide it in the module, in my case, `redis.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { redisProvider } from './redis.providers';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

@Module({
  providers: [redisProvider, RedisService],
  exports: [RedisService],
})
export class RedisModule {}
```

3. In the service, `redis.service.ts`, inject it in the constructor like this:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisClient } from './redis.providers';

@Injectable()
export class RedisService {
  public constructor(
    @Inject('REDIS_CLIENT')
    private readonly client: RedisClient,
  ) {}

  async set(key: string, value: string, expirationSeconds: number) {
    await this.client.set(key, value, 'EX', expirationSeconds);
  }

  async get(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
    return await this.client.get(key);
  }
}
```

4. Finally the test, `redis.service.spec.ts`: use the string `REDIS_CLIENT` instead of Redis imported from `ioredis`. So now it looks like this:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import * as redisMock from 'redis-mock';
import { RedisService } from './redis.service';

describe('RedisService', () => {
  let service: RedisService;
  let redisClientMock: redisMock.RedisClient;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    redisClientMock = {
      set: jest.fn(),
      get: jest.fn(),
    };
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        RedisService,
        {
          provide: 'REDIS_CLIENT',
          useValue: redisMock.createClient(),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    redisClientMock = module.get('REDIS_CLIENT');
    service = module.get<RedisService>(RedisService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
```